# webgl triangle rotate with mouse position

Tags: javascript, webgl

I want Like the gif(rotate triangle)

[image]

my code...

```
startPos[0] => first mouse down position X
startPos[1] => first mouse down position Y
endPos[0] => mousemove position X
endPos[1] => mousemove position Y

floatarray = new Float32Array(12);
floatarray[0] = startPos[0];
floatarray[1] = startPos[1];
floatarray[2] = startPos[0]*0.999;
floatarray[3] = startPos[1]*0.99;

floatarray[4] = startPos[0];
floatarray[5] = startPos[1];
floatarray[6] = startPos[0]/0.999;
floatarray[7] = startPos[1]*0.99;

floatarray[8] = startPos[0]*0.999;
floatarray[9] = startPos[1]*0.99;
floatarray[10] = startPos[0]/0.999;
floatarray[11] = startPos[1]*0.99;

gl.uniform4fv(shaderProgram.colorUniform, ['1.0','0.0','0.0','1.0']);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatarray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 6);

floatarray = new Float32Array(4);
floatarray[0] = startPos[0];
floatarray[1] = startPos[1];
floatarray[2] = endPos[0];
floatarray[3] = endPos[1];


gl.uniform4fv(shaderProgram.colorUniform, ['1.0','0.0','0.0','1.0']);
gl.bufferData(gl.ARRAY_BUFFER, floatarray, gl.STATIC_DRAW);
gl.drawArrays(gl.LINES, 0, 2);
```

[image: my result]

How do I make a dynamic rotation?...

I can not speak English.

Please understand my situation

Comment: Posting the same question multiple times will not get you an answer faster, the fact that you say you don't speak english(which I read as "give me teh codez") doesn't help either.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to rotate the points all of the points.

You can either do this by manually rotating **ALL** the points in JavaScript

```
const c = Math.cos(angleToRotateInRadians);
const s = Math.sin(angleToRotateInRadians);

rotatedPoint.x = originalPoint.x * c + originalPoint.y * s;
rotatedPoint.y = originalPoint.y * c - originalPoint.x * s;
```

or you can do it by rotating the points in your shader. Note that code above rotates around the origin (0, 0)

Inside your shader you can choose 1000s of different ways [to rotate](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-rotation.html).

The most common would be [using matrix math](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrices.html). The advantage of using matrix math is it's far more flexible. [You can easily choose the rotation point](https://webglfundamentals.org/webgl/lessons/webgl-2d-matrix-stack.html).

Comment: I have to continue using Float32Array(12);
By changing the coordinates

Comment: [radians are a unit of measurement for angles](https://ko.wikipedia.org/wiki/%EB%9D%BC%EB%94%94%EC%95%88)

Comment: do I assign your code at floatarray?? or need to modify the shader?
I need example code T_T

Comment: Sorry I'm not giving you example code. Read the articles linked. Stack Overflow is not a "give me teh codez" site